# SQL Statement that worked with SQL Database doesnt work with Access Database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, select, syntax-error

I am creating a GUI in C# and I have the following line of code to get the elements from lowerPageBound to upperPageBound.

```
command.CommandText = "Select Top " + rowsPerPage + " " +
        CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames + " From " + tableName +
        " WHERE " + columnToSortBy + " NOT IN (SELECT TOP " +
        lowerPageBoundary + " " + columnToSortBy + " From " +
        tableName + " Order By " + columnToSortBy +
        ") Order By " + columnToSortBy;
adapter.SelectCommand = command;
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
adapter.Fill(table);
```

The generated SQL statement gives me an error(adapter.Fill(table) is executed) when used on an access database but works fine on a sql database.

**Heres the SQL that is generated:**

```
Select Top 25 [ID], [Business Process], [Tier Level], [Application], [CI ID], [Server], [Server Function], [Data Center], [HA], [DR Equip], [Procedure], [Procedure Tested], [Type], [Outcome], [Overall Status] From Data WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 0 ID FROM Data ORDER BY ID) ORDER BY ID;
```

And the error I recieve:

```
Syntax error in query expression 'ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 0 ID FROM Data ORDER BY ID)'.
```

Ive tried to fix this for hours but I've had no luck. It doesn't make sense why the same statement wouldnt work on an access database. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Access sql syntax is not the same as Sql server (or other) sql varieties. What does the sql statement look like after you've finished building the string?

Comment: Can you tell me what is throwing it off then? I assumed all SQL was the same... The SQL thats generated is right underneath the C# code.

Comment: @Mohammed Do you have the ability to execute SQL directly against the Access DB?  That might be the easiest way to write your query, then rebuild it in C#

Comment: @Dan What do you mean directly against? Like try and generate it with the Access wizard?

Comment: @Mohammed Yes, that could be one option.  Although I don't like the Access wizard necessarily, but you can open up the SQL view (or something like that) and write straight SQL.  HansUp's answer below probably has your solution though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Access db engine will throw an error with this part of your query.

```
SELECT TOP 0 ID FROM Data ORDER BY ID
```

You can break out that section and test it as a new Access query.  Unfortunately, the error message is not very helpful: "*The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.*"  And that's sort of a generic error message the db engine gives you when it's unable to describe the problem precisely.

Basically, it all boils down to the fact you can not do `SELECT TOP 0` in Access SQL.

Also, once you resolve the problem about `SELECT TOP 0`, you need an `ORDER BY` clause in the outer query.  Without the `ORDER BY`, the rows returned by `TOP 25` is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess Im going to have to find another way to select all the elements between two rows.

Answer (score 3):

To perform your paging function, you can:

- Leave out the NOT IN clause when pagestart is 0.
- Use the method `SELECT TOP pagesize * FROM (SELECT TOP pagestart + pagesize * FROM X ORDER BY Condition) AS Alias ORDER BY Condition DESC`. The important part is that the second ORDER BY is in the reverse direction of the first. You may need a final ORDER BY to get the correct order, though the client should be capable of this. Note that prior to Access 2007 the designer would change that derived table (the part in parentheses) to `[SELECT ...]. AS Alias`, but now it stays.

There are more methods if these are unsatisfactory.

Less as an answer to your question and more to be informative, in addition to what HansUp has said about `TOP 0` being unsupported, you may also run into other differences between SQL Server and Access syntax. To help alleviate this, you may want to look into the DB-level setting to use SQL-Server syntax. It's not perfect, but allows some syntax that would normally fail in Access. Be aware that switching in the middle of a project can be problematic. See [info on ANSI 89 and ANSI 92 syntax incompatibilities](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-avoiding-the-mixing-of-queries-created-under-different-ansi-sql-query-modes-mdb-HP003070559.aspx).

Comment: See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-avoiding-the-mixing-of-queries-created-under-different-ansi-sql-query-modes-mdb-HP003070559.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the catches. I will update. Do you know about versions prior to Access 2003--would they accept the parentheses form?

Comment: @HansUp Do you know about versions prior to Access 2003--would they accept the parentheses form?

Comment: I don't remember those well enough, Erik.  I used older versions (97 and 2000) very little, a long time ago, and I'm an old guy so my memory is shaky anyway.  :-)